# Poetry does not install pytest neither generates basic test

Tags: python, pytest, python-poetry

I am following [this tutorial on Poetry](https://realpython.com/dependency-management-python-poetry/)

I do as written

```
poetry new rp-poetry
```

However when I inspect the folder structure, I notice that the file `test_rp_poetry.py` is not created.

Also the `__init__.py` is empty and does not contain the version

and looking at the `pyproject.toml` file I notice that there is no

```
[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]

pytest = "^5.2"
```

Has Poetry changed lately? Does the latest version require that pytest is installed manually??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Poetry 1.2 `poetry new` does not add any dependencies by default anymore. So if you want to use `pytest` you have to add it by your own.